# How to make overflow content float on top of its container?

Tags: html, css

I have created a horizontal menu with an `overflow-x: auto;` property for the wrapper `<div>`, and a `flex-wrap: nowrap;` property for the main `<ul>`'s `<li>` elements.

One of the main menu items has a couple of children. I had started with `overflow-y: hidden;` for the entire menu, and a compromise that no sub-menus would be visible.

After delivering that, I am currently puzzled if there would be an alternative solution which would allow me to include the sub-menu in my setup also. The unwanted behavior is that every `overflow-y` option that I set to the wrapper `<div>` allows my users to scroll the parent menu out of the view vertically, when the sub-menu items become visible, since the sub-menu opens vertically. Ideally I would like to allow the sub-menu to open **outside** of the container (something similar to `z-index:99999;` which I have tried, but of course did not work). Chrome Dev Tools includes an **overlay** option which looked promising, but I could not find any documentation on that, and applying it did not work either.

This is a screenshot of the horizontal menu when the sub-menu is collapsed and I have scrolled to the sub-menu parent item horizontally.

[image]

This is what it looks like when the sub-menu is expanded and I have scrolled vertically slightly. The sub-menu items are appearing in the wrapper space, but scrolling to them forces the parent menu out of the view.

[image]

This is what the entire thing looks like if I add a height of 300px to the whole wrapper, to reveal the whole of the parent and child menus.

[image]

Lastly, this is the effect that I am after.

[image]

Comment: I just read the first three words and then saw that no code, so I stopped reading. 
please share your code in a snippet and make sure it works so we can edit it for you.

Comment: My sincere apologies for that. The code is generated by a theme in Wordpress, and as a result it is bloated with tons of additional code. Even though I tried to copy that HTML element, it still didn't work, and the text editor here complained I had exceeded the limit by 5000-ish characters. That said, I tried to replicate that in a codepen, and due to the lack of some of the default classes of the theme's it does not work the same. The closest I could get it to is this:
https://codepen.io/konstantinos-sakkas/pen/vYjRREy